# Generics method call with wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I have a method `submit`:

```
<T> Future<Optional<T>> submit(Value<T> value) {
    //...
}
```

and a call of this method.

```
Value<?> value = null;
Future<Optional<?>> future = submit(value);
```

But it does not compile unless I change the signature to `Future<? extends Optional<?>> future` because `submit` returns `Future<Optional<caputure of ?>>` which is not `Future<Optional<?>>` since generics are invariant. Is there any way to give a hint to a compiler and call the method `submit` so it returns `Future<Optional<?>>`?

This snippet

```
<T, E extends Future<Optional<T>>> E submit(Value<T> value) {
  // ...
}
Value<?> value = null;
Future<Optional<?>> future = submit(value);
```

compiles as well but then I need to do unsafe cast to E before returning the value.

Here is an answer explaining the generics invariance but it still does not answer how to work with captured types.

[Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu/3547372#3547372)

Comment: Why is this a problem? As far as I can see there's no practical difference, `future.get()` will return an `Optional<?>` object.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure why using it as `Future<? extends Optional<?>>` should be a problem, there may be a solution, depending on how many contortions and "tricks" you are willing to accept.

It is not possible to compile it in the desired form, even when using the additonal type parameter `E`, simply because it is not type safe. At least, it is not possible (for the compiler) to make sure that it is type safe. The reason why it *could* not be type safe can be summarized as follows: Someone receiving the `Future<Optional<?>>` could modify the `Future`, and assign it any `Optional` - even one that has a different type than the one that it was originally created with. At a different location, someone could know the `Future` with its *original* type, and receive a `ClassCastException` when trying to use it. (I explained this with a simpler example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22193221/3182664 )

### But...

... all this is not relevant here. The `Future` interface does not allow to "set" any new value. Thus, it is perfectly feasible to convert it into a `Future` with a supertype of its original type.

Note: This is similar to the fact that you can write

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = Collections.unmodifiableList(integers);
```

This is valid (meaning "type safe") because you can not pollute the `Integer`-list with invalid `Number` instances (like `Double`s), because it's not possible to modify the list anyhow!

So one type-safe, warning-free and valid solution could be to introduce a method that "wraps" a `Future<? extends T>` and returns it as a `Future<T>`. Again: This is not really pretty, and may not be worth the effort, but at least one option:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class GenericOptionalFutureMethod
{
    void call()
    {
        Value<?> value = null;
        Future<Optional<?>> future = 
            FutureWrapper.<Optional<?>>wrap(submit(value));
    }

    <T> Future<Optional<T>> submit(Value<T> value) {
        return null;
    }
}

class FutureWrapper 
{
    static <T> Future<T> wrap(final Future<? extends T> future)
    {
        return new Future<T>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
            {
                return future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCancelled()
            {
                return future.isCancelled();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDone()
            {
                return future.isDone();
            }

            @Override
            public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
            {
                return future.get();
            }

            @Override
            public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
                throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException,
                TimeoutException
            {
                return future.get();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way of telling the compiler that your code is actually correct. You can try replacing the `?` with `Object`:

```
Value<Object> value = null;
Future<Optional<Object>> future = submit(value);
```

Comment: unfortunately `Value<?> value` is passed as a parameter to me and I can't change it's signature

Comment: You could cast is to `Value<Object>`. The risk of a ClassCastExcpetion is pretty low, I think, because not matter what the actual generic is it is always some derivation of `Object`.

Comment: @mvieghofer You can but you don't have to. Casting `Foo<?>` to `Foo<Object>` is an almost sure sign of a design fault.

Comment: @biziclop I agree with you, but I also think that passing `Value<?>` to any method (as it seems to be the case here) is also bad design. The best way would be to get rid of the `Value<?>` parameter.

Comment: @mvieghofer So how about [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))? Passing an unbounded wildcard parameter is often a sign of bad design but it has its legitimate uses.

Comment: @biziclop yeah, that's true. There obviously are legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the problem is really.

```
Future<? extends Optional<?>> future = submit(value);
Optional<?> f = future.get();
```

Compiles and runs correctly.

The answer you linked to explains it quite clearly:

`Foo<Bar>` is a `Foo<?>`

But

`Foo<Bar<X>>` isn't a `Foo<Bar<?>>`, it's a `Foo<? extends Bar<?>>`

Comment: The problem is that Optional<caputure of ?> is actually Optional<?> and I was hoping there is a way to tell the compiler to not <caputure ?> in the method signature or method call so the signature of the `future` can stay Optional<?>

Comment: This is the way to tell it. The `List` example shows you why.

Comment: why does the snippet with `E` works then? In this case it seems like ? is not captured

Comment: @user2961393 Because `E` will have to be bound to a specific class, which will have the same value in the entire expression. Whereas `?` literally means anything can go in there. I still don't see why you'd want to do an unsafe cast just to avoid the correct notation.

Comment: your example just changes the signature of future so it matches Future<Optional<capture of ?>> the ? is still captured, there should be a cleaner solution that does not require to "loose" the future's type, the code Future<Optional<?>> future = submit(value); should be still correct from the type system perspective

Comment: So for example `List<Option<E>>` would mean that when the method is called, all your `Option` instances in your list will have the same type parameter, `Option<String>` for example. Whereas `List<Option<?>>` means that the first element of the list can be `Option<String>`, the second `Option<Integer>` and so on. The two declarations are radically different.

Comment: @user2961393 No, it shouldn't. Because when you pass `Value<?>` in, what you say is this: **I don't know what parameter Value has and I don't care**. So you can't say afterwards that you want the result to have the same type as the input had because by using `?` you declared that you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to use a wildcard operator as a parameter, since you are not specifying any type on `T`. Seems to me, that it wouldn't change much.

```
Future<Optional<?>> submit(Value<?> value) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Of course it would change much since in the version with `?` the type of the input parameter does not have to match the return value. So you can pass `Value<String>` to the method but return `Future<Optional<Long>>` and that's probably not what the method should do.

Comment: the submit method should be typed meaning that the return type and parameter type should match

Comment: Yes, i know that, but he's not doing that on his example, meaning that he does not care about the specific type of the return. That's why i wrote that it wouldn't change much in **this** case.

Comment: If you say you need to match the parameters, then why you didn't pass `value` with a specific parameter, instead of a wildcard operator?