# Have SortedMap<String, String>, need SortedMap<String,Serializable>. What to do?

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

This question  regards gernerics, type-safty and Collection classes in Java:

Just as the title says: I have a method that returns a Collection, `SortedMap<String,String>`, that I retrieve from say `methodStrStr()` as return value. Say I call this method from `methodStrSer()` that just needs to pass the retrieved map along but has to return `SortedMap<String,Serializable>`.

**What is an elegant non computationally expensive way to do so?**

Without the generics I would have just returned the original map as `String` is `Serializable`. However I see that I might run into trouble at runtime if the underlying implementation of the `SortedMap` would be specific to `String` objects and result in errors if I wanted to add a different typed object such as `Boolean` which is also `Serializable` but not a `String`. So I am aware that it makes sense, that the compiler does not allow to return a `SortedMap<String,String>` as a `SortedMap<String,Serializable>`.

However, I the question remains. Is there even an acceptable way to somhow "transform" (ie a way that does not take *O(N)* time) the original map type to the target type?

Comment: Maybe you could change method signatures to return/accept `SortedMap<String, ? extends Serializable>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options:

- Copying the map - not recommended, because it may be expensive and not necessary
- As izstas suggested: Changing the signature of the receiving to accept `SortedMap<String, ? extends Serializable>` (also see [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) )
- Just provide an appropriate *view* on the map.

The latter may be the most appropriate here. You can simply write

```
SortedMap<String, String> oldMap = ...;
SortedMap<String, Serializable> newMap = 
    Collections.<String, Serializable>unmodifiableSortedMap(oldMap);
```

This is safe, because the map is unmodifiable, and thus can not be "polluted" with `Serializable` objects that are not `String`. (A simple cast, resulting in a modifiable map, would of course *not* be type-safe - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22193221/3182664) for an example why).